# Blender 2.8 - Unwrapping VS Packing

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am in UV Editor Mode, if I click unwrap (U) with a shell selected, it unwraps the shell correctly (following the seams) but at the same time it's packed in 0-1 space.

The tool is called "Unwrap" but seems it's doing "Unwrap and Pack". I can't figure out what I am doing wrong..

How can I unwrap the shell without packing it? Is it possible?

I try to show with an example:

Shell i want to modify
[image]

Mark the seam[image]
Select the shell [image]
Clicking Unwrap give me this: [image]

What i expect is something like this(just unwrap and no repack): [image]

Thank you

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136153/edit) link at the bottom of your question and add more information to help us understand your problem. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the unwrap function always unwrap inside the 0-1 area no matter what.

If you want to unwrap again some parts of your UV without affecting the rest, you can pin what you want to keep before unwrapping.
Just select in the UV Editor, then click UVs → Pin or press <kbd>P</kbd>. Don't forget to unpin when you're finished with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Yes, it's ok to unwrap inside UV0-1 but i cant understand why it unwrap and then move,scale and rotate the new shells. I've added some fast screenshots in case you have some ideas about it or its just a different workflow..Thank you

Comment: Ok then, I edited my answer.